# SSIS package Query Optimization

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oracle10g, query-optimization

I would like to have idea on how to fix a minor bug identified in the program that transfers data between an Oracle Database and a SQL server Database for a web ordering systems that I support.

The issue is, when two orders are place for instance 129 and 130 on the same day, if **the subsequent order (130)** gets verified first, the **previous web order (129)** does not get moved over to the Oracle DB. This happens because that program checks for the maximum web order transferred to Oracle DB and tries to move only SQL web order numbers higher than that.

The queries built that support this concept in the SSIS package are the following:

On the Oracle Side

```
  Select nvl(max(web_order_id),0) maxOrderIDParam from web_shipping
```

On the SQL Server side

```
  SELECT cast(web_order_id as float) web_order_id, web_entry_date, site_num, protocol_num,    inv_num, cast(pharm_num as float) pharm_num, status, comments, username, porstatus 
  FROM        Web_Shipping
  WHERE web_order_id > ?
  AND status = 'V'
  ORDER BY web_order_id
```

On the Oracle side

```
  insert into web_shipping (web_order_id, web_entry_date, site_num, protocol_num, inv_num, pharm_num, status, comments, username, porStatus) 
  values (:web_order_id, :web_entry_date, :site_num, :protocol_num, :inv_num, :pharm_num, :status, :comments, :username, :porStatus)
```

On the SQL Server side

```
     select cast(web_order_id as float) web_order_id, line_id, cast(no_of_participants as float) no_of_participants, cast(amt_inventory as float) amt_inventory, cast(NSC_num as float) NSC_num, cast(dose_str as float) dose_str, dose_unit, dose_form, dose_mult, cast(amt_req as float) amt_req 
     FROM web_ship_detail 
     WHERE web_order_id = ?
```

and finally on the Oracle side

```
    insert into web_ship_detail (web_order_id, line_id, no_of_participants, amt_inventory, NSC_num, dose_str, dose_unit, dose_form, dose_mult, amt_req) 
     values (:web_order_id, :line_id, :no_of_participants, :amt_inventory, :NSC_num, :dose_str, :dose_unit, :dose_form, :dose_mult, :amt_req)
```

The effort has been to devise a resolution with minimum code change in the whole SSIS package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you are looking for minimal code change not sure if these qualify but will 100% fix the problem.  There are 3 options:

1. Modify the MS SQL table and include a "IsTransferred" bit column.  When the verified record is moved to oracle, update the column to a 1/true
2. Keep track separate table of orders that have been transferred to Oracle.  When selecting MS SQL orders exclude those that exist in the new "transferred" table.
3. Create a Data Flow object, with the Oracle & MS SQL orders tables as sources, use a Merge Join, using left outer.  Use the results where Oracle columns are null (there is no matching Oracle records, didn't transfer) and use those records to transfer over to Oracle.

No Idea how many records are on both sides, so there may be performance concerns for some of the options.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any query you could provide to support option 1? Thank you.

Comment: Which version of MS SQL are you using?

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2008.